# Setting shared element transition between fragments residing in ViewPager

Tags: android

In my **MainActivity.java** i have a ViewPager which contains multiple fragments, on clicking on any of those fragments another fragment should open with shared element transition.

Fragment to fragment shared element transition happens properly. But when i add that code inside ViewPager shared element transition doesn't work.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: If you are using shared element in RecyclerView or ViewPager, you should assign a unique shared element name for that view and make sure to give that name also to the view in the new Fragment you are opening. Also, make sure you postpone your shared element transition until that name is given to that view. Please see this as a tutorial - https://android.jlelse.eu/dynamic-shared-element-transition-23428f62a2af